# how can i convert the result of PDO fetchAll to a string?

Tags: php, pdo

How could I convert my `fetchAll()` result to a string? Like iterating over the contents of the array that is returned with my fetch all and trying to echo them is giving me an "Array to string conversion" error.
I would like to echo each value of the array.

```php
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT company_name, job_name, job_description, job_location, contact_email FROM joblist");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    print_r($result);
    // echo $result[0];
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
```

My result looks like this:

```php
Array (
    [company_name] => alex
    [0] => alex
    [job_name] => driver
    [1] => driver
    [job_description] => drive a truck with goods
    [2] => drive a truck with goods
    [job_location] => america
    [3] => america
    [contact_email] => alex@email.com
    [4] => alex@email.com
)
```

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   `C:\xampp\htdocs\jobs-app\postjob.php` on line 23

Answer (score 1):

**$value is array format.So you can't echo array.**

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
   echo $value['job_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array inside an array, Echoing it out like this should work

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo $value[0];
}
```

If you want to make it be more precise you should do this

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['company_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$value in your foreach is array. Try this.

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
   echo $value['company_name'];
}
```